# JSON iteration for Google Maps in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

In my rails I have a hidden input that should be pulling in the JSON data for manipulation that looks like the following in my Region > Show page.

My regions_controller has the following for show:

```
def show
@region = Region.find_by!(url_name: params[:id])
@locations = @region.locations
@careers = @region.careers
@training_events = @region.training_events
respond_with @region
end

<div class="banner" id="region-banner" data-region-name="#{@region.name.downcase}">
 </div>
 <input id="points" type="hidden" data-value="#{@locations.to_json}" />
```

Then in my JS file I have:

```
import { mapStyle } from './styles/mapStyle';

app.regions = () => {
  function init() {
    startGoogleMap();
   }

  let startGoogleMap = () => {
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('region-banner'), {
      zoom: 3,
      minZoom: 3,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
      styles: mapStyle
    });
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('region-banner');
    const regionName = mapElement.getAttribute('data-region-name');
    let dataElement = document.getElementById('points');
    let pointMarkers = mapElement.getAttribute('data-value');
    console.log(pointMarkers);
    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var key in pointMarkers){
      if (pointMarkers.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      var value = pointMarkers[key];
      console.log(value);
      }
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  };

  return init();
};
```

Beyond the fact that I'm getting null for pointMarkers. How do I iterate through and add in the positions? I've tried the following:

```
for (let i=0; i < pointMarkers.length, i++) {
  pointMarkers[i]: {
    position: {(lat, lng)},
    map: map,
    icon: '/marker.png'
  }
}
```

No errors are showing but I think that's because it's still pulling in as null for pointMarkers.

I've even tried the following thinking it was probably closer:

```
for (let i=0; i < pointMarkers.length; i++) {
  position = (pointMarkers[i].lat, pointMarkers[i].lng),
  map: map,
  icon: '/marker.png'
};
```

I end up getting Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ; (32:9) for the map: map line.

EDIT:
I've also tried the following that happens with the same error as above:

```
 for (let i=0; i < pointMarkers.length; i++) {
  let marker = new google.maps.Markers({
    position: (data.lat[i], data.lng[i])
  },
  map: map,
  icon: '/marker.png'
)};
```

Another EDIT:
Have tried this as well:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < pointMarkers.length; i++) {
  pointMarkers[i] = new google.map.Marker({
    position: { lat: data.lat[i], lng: data.lng[i] },
    map: pointMarkers[i].map,
    icon: '/marker.png'
  });
}
```

With this I end up getting the following in console:

```
[{"id": 2, "name": "Chicago", "lat" : "22.222", "lng": "19.19191"},{"id": 3, "name": "Detroit", "lat" : "32.232", "lng": "22.19191"}]
[
{
"
i
d
```

Then everything broken out. But it doesn't mark the map.

Additional EDIT:
Have the following code present:

```
 for (let i = 0; i <= pointMarkers.length; i++) {
  pointMarkers[i] = {
    position: {
      lat: parseFloat(pointMarkers.lat[i]),
      lng: parseFloat(pointMarkers.lng[i])
    },
    map: pointMarkers[i].map,
    icon: '/marker.png'
  };
}
```

It errors at lat: parseFloat(pointMarkers.lat[i]) with Cannot read property '0' of undefined after displaying:

```
[
{
"
i
d
```

And so on.

Closer but not correct EDIT:

```
let marked = JSON.parse(pointMarkers);

function placeMarker() {
for(let i in marked){
    let lat  = marked[i].lat;
    let lng  = marked[i].lng;
    let title = marked[i].name;
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map: map,
            icon: '/marker.png',
            title: title
        });
     };
};
```

This will actually give me an object but not actually applying the markers.

So how do iterate over JSON object and apply google markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the following my js file:

```
import { tns } from 'tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider.module';
import { mapStyle } from './styles/mapStyle';

app.regions = () => {
 function init() {
   startGoogleMap();
 }

 let startGoogleMap = () => {
   let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('region-banner'), {
     zoom: 3,
     minZoom: 3,
     disableDefaultUI: true,
     gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
     styles: mapStyle
   });

   let mapElement = document.getElementById('region-banner');
   const regionName = mapElement.getAttribute('data-region-name');
   let pointMarkers = mapElement.getAttribute('data-value');
   let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   let marked = JSON.parse(pointMarkers);

   marked.forEach(marked => {
     let lat = parseFloat(marked.lat);
     let lng = parseFloat(marked.lng);

     const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
       map,
       icon: '/marker.png',
       title: marked.name
     });
     bounds.extend(marker.position);
   });

   map.fitBounds(bounds);
 };

 return init();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for (let i=0; i < pointMarkers.length, i++) {
  pointMarkers[i] = { // you were missing the assignment operator here
    position: [pointMarkers[i].lat, pointMarkers[i].lng],
    // or as lat, lon as an object,
    //position: {
    //   lat: pointMarkers[i].lat,
    //   lng: pointMarkers[i].lng,
    // }
    map: pointMarkers[i].map,
    icon: '/marker.png'
  }
}
```

You can't do something like this

```
position: (data.lat[i], data.lng[i]) , meaningless
```

You can do these

```
position: [data.lat[i], data.lng[i]],                     as an array
position: {"lat" : data.lat[i], "lng": data.lng[i] },     as an object
```

Since google marker accepts float values you need to use parseFloat(),

```
position: {
  "lat" : parseFloat(data.lat[i]),
  "lng": parseFloat(data.lng[i])
},
```

Comment: Updated my code. Gave this a try but it's not actually applying markers.

Comment: @Jake Go through this, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers.

Values of lat & lng must be float whereas its string as of now. read the docs carefully

Comment: Using the parseFloat like that actually causes an error of: data not defined.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Maybe data is actually undefined. Use try-catch

Comment: Ran:     try {
      a = JSON.parse(pointMarkers);
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e); // You get an error.
    }. a is undefined

Comment: You have to define **a** prior using it,
try { let a = JSON.parse(pointMarkers); } catch (e) { alert(e); // You won't get any error. }.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168426/discussion-between-satish-kumar-and-jake).

Comment: @Jake You have to define a prior using it, try { let a = JSON.parse(pointMarkers); } catch (e) { alert(e); // You won't get any error. }.